# Как вывести фигурные скобки с переменной в Python c помощью f-строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, вывод, f-strings

Мне необходимо вывести фигурные скобки с переменной внутри. Смог найти только способ вывода скобок как строки целиком:

```
key = 1
city = 'City'
value = 22

print(f"{{key}}: {{city}} - {{str(value)}}")        #{key}: {city} - {str(value)}
```

А так выдает ошибку:

```
key = 1
city = 'City'
value = 22

print(f"{\n    {key}: {city} - {str(value)}\n}")
```

Необходимый вывод:

```
{
    1: Сity - 22
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не забывайте, что в f-строках символы `{` и `}` являются управляющими, поэтому, при необходимости вывести их как строки, их нужно экранировать путем удвоения, подробнее можно почитать [в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can
> be escaped by **doubling**:
> {{ and }}.

Код:

```
key = 1
city = 'City'
value = 22

print(f'{{\n\t {key}: {city} - {value} \n}}')
```

Вывод:

```
{
    1: City - 22 
}
```